# How to decide schema version numbers with Flyway for multirepo project

Tags: git, version-control, dependencies, microservices, versioning

We are developing n-tier application, where the *frontend*, *backend*, *database-migrator*  and *docker-compose environment* components are stored and developed in their own repositories. They are built, unit tested and containerized independently by the CI/CD pipeline. Currently, *semantic version* is used to tag the backend component master builds. Docker-compose project should should setup the development environment with correct component versions.

What is the best way to holistically track compatibility between n-tier application component development and release versions with decomposed repositories? Git submodules are no-go due their security issues. We should utilize docker registry and tags for version management. Git tags are used to tag docker images.

I'm especially unsure how to specify versions for database migrations. What are the rules for version bumping (major/minor) at the schema level and the migrator image level? How should the schema version relate to image version (different image versions may have different "unversioned" repeatable scripts, i.e view and procedures => possible breaking change).

Also, I'm unsure how to version frontend, as there are no dependents. Ultimately, I would like to maintain version history where it's possible to deploy previous version of the system if needed.

TLDR: How to use semantic versioning in multi-repository project for frontend, backend, database migrations and docker-compose-environment with CI/CD pipeline and container registry?

Answer (score 0):

Common setup for Flyway is to have it integrated in your microservice (likely in your back-end in this case). This way your migrations go alongside your code. If you have several microservices using databases, each of them would have its own migrations. Separating migrations into a separate repository from back-end code is not usually a best practice.

Regarding mixing different versions of microservices - see my article here for more context - https://worklifenotes.com/2020/03/04/microservices-combinatorial-explosion-of-versions/ . I'm currently working on a tool to address this problem - https://relizahub.com . Essentially, we automatically record different possible states of projects as "bundles", and then you rely on these bundles as single point of truth of the versioning of your whole stack. There is also specific tooling to route your CI/CD to correct bundles, including business rules for manual and automatic gates.